# Using JSON with chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I trying to use json file and create pie chart using chart.js from www.chartjs.org.

This is my JSON file:

```
[
   {
        value: 300,
        color: "#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },

    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },

    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    },

    {
        value: 40,
        color: "#949FB1",
        highlight: "#A8B3C5",
        label: "Grey"
    },

    {
        value: 120,
        color: "#4D5360",
        highlight: "#616774",
        label: "Dark Grey"
    }
]
```

My javascript code is:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({

    url: "pie.json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(pieData) {
            var ctx = $("#chart-area").get(0).getContext("2d");
            new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
    }
   });  });
```

I can see that JSON file is loaded in the browser but for some reason chart is not created.
Looks that chart.js takes arrays and I tried to create one from JSON object but that did not help.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ywtwmeof/1/ - any error in your browser console

Comment: hi, no errors, really do not know what is wrong. When I hard code json file (array to file) it works but when json is from online resource it does not.

Comment: ajax also is working - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ywtwmeof/2/ - look at the data returned from your ajax request... add `console.log(pieData)` in your success handler and see what is logged

Comment: Hmm this is strange (I am using Firebug), but `console.log(pieData)` does not return anything I get only `POST http://.../pie.json 200 OK 1ms`. I see that JSFIDDLE is working but still can not get it working on my computer.

Comment: that means your ajax request is not returning the proper data